# capture web page content wpf web browser

Tags: wpf, browser, html

I want to programmatically (WPF, C#) log in to my financial accounts website (https) and retrieve some of my account data.  Because the site uses cookies, and other session validation, I think that the best way is to use a web browser control, rather than an httpWebRequest.  I cannot seem to capture the screen content.

I was able to do this successfully using winforms, but I want to do it in WPF.  Here is a code snippet from the winforms project:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate( @"https://myfinancialaccountURL" );
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(
                                                      wb1DocumentCompleted );

private void wb1DocumentCompleted( object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e )
{
    string wb1LogonScreen = webBrowser1.DocumentText;

    --- process the data, etc.  ---
}
```

Here is a code snippet from the WPF attempt:

```
webBrowser1.Navigated += new NavigatedEventHandler( webBrowser1_Navigated );
webBrowser1.Navigate( @"https:myfinancialaccountURL" );
```

I have extensively researched the WPF  web browser control, and it has a Document property, but I cannot figure out how to get the content (or inner text).

I have researched this but am still unable to find the answer.  Please tell me if I need to provide more information.  I would greatly appreciate some help here.

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can read the Document property as an MSHTML.Document and then use that to get the text. You need to include the Microsoft.mshtml library in your project.

```
  mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = null;
        string docState = string.Empty;

       // CODE TO ENSURE THAT THE DOCUMENT AND THE SCRIPTS HAVE LOADED
        Action getDocState = () =>
        {
            doc = wb.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
            if (null != doc)
            {
                docState = doc.readyState;
            }
        };

        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                    DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    getDocState);


        if (null != doc)
        {
            while ((docState != "complete") && (docState != "interactive"))
            {
                // It should not take more than one or two iterations for the document to get loaded.
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                    DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    getDocState);
                }
            }
       // DOC SHOULD BE LOADED AND READABLE NOW

            // Go back to the UI thread to get more details
            if (!App.Current.Dispatcher.HasShutdownStarted)
            {
               // This line is of your interest here
                MessageBox.Show(doc.documentElement.innerHTML);
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**: You can use this code in your navigated event handler. The reason I have the wait for doc to load code is that once WPF load/navigate is complete, the web browser loads the HTML and the scripts etc. This script ensures that the doc is completely loaded and in a state where you can interact with it.

Comment: Thank you.  I will give this a try and report the results.

Comment: I know this answer never got selected by the asker, but I just tried it and it works!